# The function $w(z)=-(\frac1z+bz),-1<b<1 ,$ maps $|z|<1$ onto ...

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> The function $w(z)=-(\frac1z+bz),-1<b<1 ,$ maps $|z|<1$ onto
>   (A) A half plane
>   (B) Exterior of the circle
>   (C) Exterior of an Ellipse
>   (D) Interior of an ellipse

I tried by replacing $z=re^{i \theta}$ but I must admit that I have not gotten very far .Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=re^{it}$ with $0 \le r<1$. Then 
$$-w(z)=(\frac{1}{r}e^{-it}+bre^{it})=(\frac{1}{r}+br)\cos t+i(-\frac{1}{r}+br)\sin t$$
Let $r=1$, you get the boundary of $-\mathrm{im} \,w$, which is $\big((1+b)\cos t,(b-1)\sin t\big)$. This is an ellipse (circle if $b=0$). Since $-w(z)\to \infty$ as $r\to 0$, $\mathrm{im} \,w$ is the exterior of an ellipse (circle if $b=0$).

Answer (score 0):

Ma Ming has provided an answer which works well even without the aid of multiple choices.  With the use of the four choices, we can find our answer with even less work:

Since $w$ maps $0 \mapsto \infty$, (d) cannot hold.

Since $w(z)$ can be continously extended to the boundary $\vert z \vert =1$, the image of this boundary under $w$ must be a (compact) closed curve.  This eliminates (a).

This leaves only (b)  and (c).  Technically, (b) implies (c), so we'd be done (in a multiple-choice testing environment).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it.It's a good way to tackle this type of questions.